# Where can I find an official grammar for the PL/SQL programming language?

Tags: plsql, grammar, context-free-grammar

Where can I find an official grammar for the PL/SQL programming language? I see that the [Antlr project](http://www.antlr.org/) has [a user-contributed grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1279318813752/PLSQL.g), but I was hoping to find a more authoritative source.

Comment: Making it easier for 3rd parties to parse their language is not something I would expect from Oracle.

Comment: @mikerobi: True enough! I can still be hopeful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the documentation?  It'd help to know what version of Oracle -- [this link covers 9i (v9.2 technically)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/toc.htm).

Comment: I think he is referring to the grammar definitions necessary to parse the language.

Comment: I had seen that documentation before, but I had never noticed the [PL/SQL Language Elements section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems.htm#37784). Although it is not a unified grammar, it certainly provides the components needed for the various elements!

Comment: For 11g see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/langelems.htm

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can take a look at a community [PL/SQL ANTLR grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql) in ANTLR grammars repository.

Answer (score 1):

The official grammar for the PL/SQL can be found at the [Chapter 13](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/langelems.htm#LNPLS013) of the [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm).