# List of Tables in SQL File

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

How could I get all the tables in `.sql` file with a lot of plsq/ anonymous blocks? The ideal would had been get it through data dictionaries but it's not possible because they're not in the database.

I was thinking read the text with regular expressions: does anybody have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can guarantee that the SQL is in a certain format making it easy to pick out tables, what you will need is a PLSQL/SQL lexical analyser.

See this for details :

[Where can I find an official grammar for the PL/SQL programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884211/where-can-i-find-an-official-grammar-for-the-pl-sql-programming-language)

To illustrate my point, take this example:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM tabA, tabB
WHERE x = y;
```

will work if you `grep 'FROM[:space:]' | cut -d' ' -f2`.

But, if you have:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM tabA,
     tabB
WHERE c IN ( SELECT x
             FROM tabC,
                  tabD
.
.
```

Then things get tricky, and you need  Lex/Yacc type grammar analyser.

UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE should be fairly simple:

```
egrep '(UPDATE|INSERT|DELETE)[:space:]' src.sql | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Should get you started.

But, once you get more flowery layouts you will find it starts to miss things.